# Calling C++/CLI from C# becomes slower with time

Tags: c#, c++-cli, interop

I'm writing a C++/CLI wrapper library for a C++ library. C++/CLI is not my preferred language, but after a few hit and misses, I've managed to produce a managed library I can use from C#.

The problem is that, with time, calling functions gradually becomes slower. At first it takes about 3-4ms (measured with Stopwatch) and then it gradually increases to 4000ms and beyond.

These are the relevant pieces of code. Note that I've removed things as namespaces and also combined .cpp/.h files to make it easier to read.

**Program.cs**

```
using (var session = new Session())
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch;
    var handle = session.Add(addParams);

    while (true)
    {
        stopWatch.StartNew();
        handle.GetStatus(); // This call is gradually getting slower.
        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}ms to get status.", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**Session.h**

```
public ref class Session
{
private:
    void* _pointer;

    property libtorrent::session* Pointer
    {
        inline libtorrent::session* get()
        {
            return (libtorrent::session*)this->_pointer;
        }
    }

public:
    Session()
    {
        this->_pointer = new libtorrent::session();
    }

    TorrentHandle^ Add(AddTorrentParams ^addTorrentParams)
    {
        auto handle = this->Pointer->add_torrent(*addTorrentParams->Pointer);
        return gcnew TorrentHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

**TorrentHandle.h**

```
public ref class TorrentHandle
{
private:
    void* _pointer;

    property libtorrent::torrent_handle* Pointer
    {
        inline libtorrent::torrent_handle* get()
        {
            return (libtorrent::torrent_handle*)this->_pointer;
        }
    }

internal:
    TorrentHandle(libtorrent::torrent_handle const &handle)
    {
        this->_pointer = (void*) new libtorrent::torrent_handle(handle);
    }

public:
    TorrentStatus^ GetStatus()
    {
        return gcnew TorrentStatus(this->Pointer->status());
    }
}
```

**TorrentStatus.h**

```
public ref class TorrentStatus
{
private:
    void* _pointer;

    property libtorrent::torrent_status* Pointer
    {
        inline libtorrent::torrent_status* get()
        {
            return (libtorrent::torrent_status*)this->_pointer;
        }
    }

public:
    TorrentStatus(libtorrent::torrent_status &status)
    {
        this->_pointer = (void*)new libtorrent::torrent_status(status);
    }
}
```

I know that some of the `void*` casting may be unnecessary, but I can't see how those can become slower and slower.

**Output on a normal run**

```
0ms to get status
0ms to get status
0ms to get status
1ms to get status
94ms to get status
18ms to get status
15ms to get status
68ms to get status
114ms to get status
112ms to get status
123ms to get status
130ms to get status
220ms to get status
210ms to get status
371ms to get status
277ms to get status
1152ms to get status
1081ms to get status
1384ms to get status
1424ms to get status
1387ms to get status
1520ms to get status
1471ms to get status
605ms to get status
1201ms to get status
1038ms to get status
1672ms to get status
```

What causes this slowing behavior?

Comment: Are you cleaning up your unmanaged resources somewhere outside of this code?

Comment: Yes, in the C++/CLI class destructors.

Comment: Your call isn't getting slower, you're using the same `Stopwatch` over and over again, use `Stopwatch.StartNew()` instead of `Start` (or reset it after each iteration).

Comment: I can assure you the call *is* getting slower. I agree with you on the Stopwatch code having a bug - however, the wall clock time is increasing even so.

Comment: @aevitas I've edited the question to include the Stopwatch fixes and console output.

Comment: Do you have the same behavior in native program?

Comment: What does `var handle = session.Add(addParams);` look like? You're adding a session every iteration by the looks of it, which means your test case isn't equal every time you take measure. We can only *guess* what the problem is, I have no idea what a `Session` is, and how those objects are allocated and cleaned up.

Comment: I've added the summarized Session.h as well. Also, the `Add` call is outside the loop and does not take any considerable time to run - it is the `GetStatus` call which takes longer and longer.

Comment: Perhaps the performance of `GetStatus` depends on the activity in the torrent client, ie the active downloads or the connected peers. If you start it up there is little activity, but as it runs it starts to get more and more connections. I agree with Alex, test this in a native program.

Comment: Herman, Alex - I've tested in a native program and indeed, the calls are getting slower and slower. Might have to look on how I compile libtorrent - right now it is compiled as a static library.

Comment: @ViktorElofsson Compiling it as a static library should be fine, as long as it's linked to in your C++/CLI library. You may have actually found a quirk in libtorrent; it's probably a good idea to touch base with them and report your findings. If anything, their developers will know more about how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. When compiling libtorrent in *Release* mode, everything ran as it should. I guess there's some heavy asserts going on when running debug.

Comment: This does not explain, why the code gets slower **over time**. Anyway, Visual Studio has a fine profiler. Go ahead, use it.

Comment: It was dependent on load as well - the slowdowns were around 1-1.5s when libtorrent tried to get as much speed as possible from torrents. The asserts then caused the slowdowns.